# Integrate static database with spatial database

Tags: qgis, spatial-database, oracle-spatial, integration

I have some questions about how to integrate static database with spatial databases.

problematic:

I have several static data bases on different platforms (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server) I want to turn into spatial data for some users to work in QGIS.

Step 1: geocode data 
Initially I wanted to create a routine to geocode the data using OSM and OpenLayers.

Step 2: Provision of the data in spatial database 
These data should be available in Oracle Spatial (is a standardization that I follow). This is where my questions begin what better way to do this integration? 
There are business information that should not go to the bank so I have space, for example, a SQL Server based with static data a routine that geocodes the data and provides the correposndentes in Oracle Spatial geometries. That is the best?

Comment: What do you mean by "static data" ? Do you mean you have tables with street addresses that you want to use spatially ?

Comment: Exactly, there is an automated way to do this integration between different databases?

Answer (score 1):

I am still not clear about what exactly you want to do. If you are asking about how different kinds of databases can interoperate and be accessed by the same application, then that should be possible by using the APIs specific for each type of database.

For a java-based development that would be using the proper jdbc drivers: use the jdbc driver for SQL Server to access that one, and the jdbc driver for Oracle to access Oracle databases.

If you are thinking about using one database environment and access a different kind of database from that environment, that is possible too, at least from Oracle and for some other databases: check out the Oracle Database Gateways (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/gateways/index.html) that let you connect to a SQL Server database from within an Oracle database.

If you are thinking about something else, then be more specific.